# Change Owner From "root" in VMware's Shared Folder

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, chown

I'm running a Xubuntu from a Windows 8 host. I can't change the owner of shared files from xubuntu by any `sudo chown ...` command. Is there any other way I can change the owner from the `root` to the `user`? I also have tried to mount the shared folder into home directory, still didn't change anything

```
hooman@ubuntu:~/win/meteor$ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Dec 10 19:03 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16384 Dec 11 18:30 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Dec 10 19:03 simple-todos
hooman@ubuntu:~/win/meteor$
```

**Edit:**

after doing `sudo chown`:

```
hooman@ubuntu:~/win/meteor$ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Dec 10 19:03 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16384 Dec 11 18:30 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Dec 10 19:03 simple-todos
hooman@ubuntu:~/win/meteor$ sudo chown -v hooman simple-todos/
changed ownership of ‘simple-todos/’ from root to hooman
hooman@ubuntu:~/win/meteor$ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Dec 10 19:03 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16384 Dec 11 18:30 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Dec 10 19:03 simple-todos
```

Comment: Please avoid screenshots of terminals and post text instead.

Comment: @Hooman can you pls post `sudo chown` and it's output you've tried?

Comment: @Simply_Me Sure; I edited the post

Comment: These are *shared files*, so it’s not a real POSIX-compliant filesystem but a virtual construct of VMware. To change the virtual permissions, typically some mount options or other configuration of the sharing mechanism is required, instead of chown/chmod.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
`sudo chown -v hooman. simple-todos/` 
Dont forget the dot after hooman

ls -l | grep simple

drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Dec 12 11:23 simple-todo

sudo chown -v kaustubh. simple-todos/

changed ownership of `simple-todos/' from root:root to kaustubh:kaustubh

kaustubh@hacked:~/test$

ls -l | grep simple

drwxr-xr-x 2 kaustubh kaustubh 4096 Dec 12 11:23 simple-todos

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not working either.

Comment: try adding -R i.e sudo chown -vR hooman. simple-todos this must work

Comment: already tried that. No change ...